# Dynamic drop down from database in jsp not working

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu

I m trying to populate a drop down menu.The second and third drop down list should show values after retrieving from the database as per the previous drop down value selected.Can any one you point out the error in my code.When i run the code I cant select any value in any of the drop down. Plz help me.
[Country.jsp](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byr1U6uyUqbaYXQyc0pWYmJmRWM/edit)

[State.jsp](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byr1U6uyUqbaMGNUdkRKdXU1SjA/edit)

City.jsp  is almost the same as state.jsp

I have already added values in the database. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please use predefined frameworks like JSTL/SQL and jQuery.js

This should work:

```
<%--
    Document   : index
    Created on : Jan 23, 2013, 7:43:24 PM
    Author     : Ankit
--%>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<sql:setDataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" user="system" password="ankit" var="db" scope="request" />
<sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="countrys" sql="SELECT * FROM country" />
<sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="states" sql="SELECT * FROM state WHERE countryid=${param['countryid']}" />
<sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="cities" sql="SELECT * FROM city WHERE cityid=${param['cityid']}" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <select name="countryid" id="countrylist" onclick="jQuery('#statelist').load('?countryid='+jQuery(this).val(),'#statelist');">
            <c:forEach items="${countrys}" var="country">
                <option value="${country.id}">${country.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <select name="stateid" id="statelist" onclick="jQuery('#citylist').load('?cityid='+jQuery(this).val(),'#citylist');">
            <c:forEach items="${states}" var="state">
                <option value="${state.id}">${state.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <select name="cityid" id="citylist">
            <c:forEach items="${cities}" var="city">
                <option value="${city.id}">${city.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <button>Finish</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```